# Tabulator formatting negative money using accounting principles

Tags: tabulator

Love this tool. But using the built-in formatters I can't figure out how to format money when negative with parentheses around it instead of the negative character.

so like (1000) and not -1000

If I need to do something custom I can work with that too.

Comment: It doesn't look like there is a built in way to do that with the money/currency formatter.  You need to create your own formatter that does what you are looking for.  If you need help with that, I can give you an example.

Comment: I added a new formatter directly into the main tabulator file. The other method didn't work right for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
moneyParen: function money(cell, formatterParams, onRendered) {
        var floatVal = parseFloat(cell.getValue()),
            number,
            integer,
            decimal,
            rgx;

        var decimalSym = formatterParams.decimal || ".";
        var thousandSym = formatterParams.thousand || ",";
        var symbol = formatterParams.symbol || "";
        var after = !!formatterParams.symbolAfter;
        var precision = typeof formatterParams.precision !== "undefined" ? formatterParams.precision : 2;

        if (isNaN(floatVal)) {
            return this.emptyToSpace(this.sanitizeHTML(cell.getValue()));
        }

        number = precision !== false ? floatVal.toFixed(precision) : floatVal;
        number = String(number).split(".");

        integer = number[0];
        decimal = number.length > 1 ? decimalSym + number[1] : "";

        var isNeg = (integer.includes("-"));

        if (isNeg === true) { integer = integer.replace("-", ""); }

        rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;

        while (rgx.test(integer)) {
            integer = integer.replace(rgx, "$1" + thousandSym + "$2");
        }



        var retPt1 = after ? integer + decimal + symbol : symbol + integer + decimal;

        return isNeg ? "(" + retPt1 + ")" : retPt1;
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, this was very helpful. FYI, you might want to change the last line of the function to keep right justification alignment of positive and negative numbers:

```
return isNeg ? "(" + retPt1 + ")" : retPt1 + "&nbsp;";
```